# How to capture the input to form the output directory in makefile

Tags: linux, perl, makefile

I was using the original makefile to build my code with Perl scripts written in makefile.

Now I want to print all the log shown on screen to a txt file.

What command can I use in my makefile in order to do this?

I was meant to use some command in makefile to output what will be shown on screen to a txt file.

And I need to save the output to a txt file whose directory should according to the input of my perl script.

For example, in the makefile:

```
all:

   $(X)make -C .. DIR=$(DIR) Y=$(Y) Z=$(Z)
   perl filename.pl $(DIR)/$(Y)/i.lst 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

how should I change in the makefile so that the log.txt will be saved at the directory equals the input $DIR? Ans I also want to change the name "log" to the input, how could I do this?

Can anyone help?

Comment: What name do you want the text file to have?

Comment: You just need pick a different file name in the argument to `tee` to change the name of the logged file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reading of your question suggests this answer to me

```
all:

   $(X)make -C .. DIR=$(DIR) Y=$(Y) Z=$(Z) 2>&1 | tee $(DIR)/log.txt
   perl filename.pl $(DIR)/$(Y)/i.lst 2>&1 | tee -a $(DIR)/log.txt
```

Comment: @etan-reisner might be an idea if you answered separately?